# Firebase Security Rules - prevent duplicate friend request

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

For my iOS App I allow users to make friend requests that are similar in principle to a Facebook friend request. Someone can therefore have x number of friends.

I would like to prevent a user from sending more then one friend request to the same user and was hoping to do this by adding a validation rule in the database rules - (I haven't yet explored the option of having another list yet)

The current validation rule I have is to prevent a user from sending a friend request to themselves.

Below is the structure of the database where I need to check that the values for 'fromUid' and 'toUid' both don't already exist as a pair together.

```
    "requests" : {

        "-KUr12h72I4T2WiI4JG0" : { // autoChildId

             "fromUid" : "etOdpR0wpKYNFrIP7BNirhCYuYo1",
             "toUid" : "UeATHfKdjVYunsOt8L0TGxfCBTQ2"
    }
```

The current rules I have prevents a user from sending a friend request to themselves

```
    "requests": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        "$autoID": {
            ".validate": "newData.child('fromUid').val() != newData.child('toUid').val()"
         }
    },
```

So how can I validate that the 'fromUid' value and 'toUid' value don't already exist as a pair together? i.e this friend request hasn't already been made.

This was my failed attempt for the security rules:

```
        ".validate": "&& newData.child('fromUid').val() + newData.child('toUid').val() !== data.child('fromUid').val() + data.child('toUid').val() && newData.child('toUid').val() + newData.child('fromUid').val() !== data.child('toUid').val() + data.child('fromUid').val()"
```

Please let me know if you need more information or clarity
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good (and correct) database structure is more then half of the project. If you design your database structure badly you will be in a big trouble especially when you work with NOSQL database. If you spend time beforehand on designing database you will be happy later.

You should design the project and think beforehand what operations you need, How do you want to show the data who has what roles and design your firebase database according to it.

My recommendation is to read the following page about structuring data from firebase documentation.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

## About your problem

I suggest modifying database structure and group `toUid`s by `fromUid`.

```
{
    "requests": {
        // user Ids who sent request
        "userId1": {
            // receiver ids
            "userId2": true,
            "userId3": true,
            "userId4": true
        },
        "userId2": {
            "userId3": true,
            "userId4": true
        }
    }
}
```

Here duplicated requests are impossible. The only check what you have to do is that user could not send request to himself.

Here is rules for this.

```
"requests": {
  ".write": "auth != null",
  "$senderId": {
    "$receiverId": {
      ".validate": "$senderId !== $receiverId"
    }
  }
}
```

With this structure you can easily do other operations also. For example to get all requests by `fromUid`. To check if `userId1` sent request to `userId2`, etc.

Comment: Not sure why I was structuring my data the way I did. There is no need in this case to add an autoByChildId() key and subsequently have a toUid and fromUid node, as the user's uid is unique and its a one of event. This structure makes things a lot easier :), Cheers

Comment: Great!... It would be good if you accept the answer and click upper arrow. This will help others know that this answer is useful

Comment: Just did - sorry still new to this - Unfortunately I can't upvote as I don't have the reputation yet

Comment: Ok. Be active and your reputation will grow.